# Error "next: not found" while starting nextjs standalone in Azure Web App

Tags: reactjs, node.js, azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service

I have a problem with deploying an application written in the *Next.js* framework to an *Azure Web App*. Following the instructions I found on the *Microsoft* website, I compiled the application with the "standalone" flag, which created an additional folder called `./.next/standalone`.

[image]

I compressed this folder and installed it in the `/home/site/wwwroot` directory of the *Azure Web App*. When I run the `npm start` command in this directory, I get the following result:

```
sh 1: next: not found
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to deploy to a static web app service/ Azure web app?  Could you share your Version details? reference used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error "next: not found" while starting nextjs standalone in Azure Web App

The error message “next: not found” means that the Next.js runtime is not installed or is not in the path.

But the next app runs with the command `npm run dev` or `npm run sart`.

In **Local:**

Create a next app from this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs-hybrid).

`npm init next-app@next-12-3-2 --typescript`

[image]

[image]

To create a [standalone](https://medium.com/@sagarpoojary424/create-standalone-build-for-your-next-js-app-c9d4f5061d03) build for your Next.js app, you can follow these [steps](https://github.com/Sagar848/my-nextjs-app):

1. **Remove the `output: 'export'` option from your `next.config.js` file.**

**next.config.js:**

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This is necessary because you want to create a dynamic build, which is not possible with static exports.

- **Build your app after modify `package.json` Scripts with `next build && nextjs-standalone-deployer.exe` command.**

**package.json:**

```json
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && nextjs-standalone-deployer.exe",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

This will create a `build` folder containing all of the necessary files to run your app standalone.

[image]

- I followed the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode#configure-the-app-service-app-and-deploy-code) for the Deploy from VSCode.
- **Deploy the `build` folder to any server that supports Node.js.**

[image]

**Deployement Status :**

[image]

**In Azure:**
[image]